# Why weren't the Birches also being charged?

Tags: plot-explanation, prisoners

Towards the end of [*Prisoners* (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392214/) in the hospital scene we learn that Keller is being charged of torturing and kidnapping Alex (well the allegations are not clearly mentioned but somewhat implied). That information couldn't be only deduced from detective Loki's testimony. He didn't actually see Keller kidnapping and torturing Alex. At some point Alex should have spoken, too and that should lead to Birches being charged with the same allegations.

We don't see the Birches even being disturbed about this fact. They were happy to have their daughter back and freely walking around.

Is there some plot hole in it or is there some other explanation for it?

Comment: *"the allegations are not clearly mentioned but somewhat implied"* - So are they charging him for that or not? And are they charging him (for which you need some evidence) or just investigating him yet (for which Loki's testimony *would* be enough)?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I was meaning that when Loki responded by saying "Probably" to Grace's half question "and he'll go to jail" it's clear that he'll be charged but it's not verbalized for which reasons. I'm mostly disturbed by the fact that the Birches did partake in the torture but they seem to be OK with it despite only their friend being charged and the reasonable threat of Alex mentioning and identifying them as the other torturers.

Answer (score 5):

**The movie is unclear about whether the Birches will be charged.**

The Birches clearly aided and abetted Keller Dover, so if he is charged, they 
would likely also be charged with some lesser crime(s).

However, given the extreme circumstances in play, it's not certain that even Keller Dover will be charged. When Keller's wife asks Detective Loki if Keller is going to jail, Loki says "probably" but not "yes."

At the end of the movie, the Birches don't seem too concerned about potential charges because they had just got their daughter back and were focused on her.